# Unable to get whole http message

Tags: sockets, http, curl

I am using curl for sending a **POST HTTP** message to my server. At Server side I am opening a socket and reading the data by using following code

```
recv(socket_Fd, (void *)ucBuffer, (size_t)((sizeof(ucBuffer) - 1)), NULL);
```

I am able to get the header of the **POST** message but in message body I am getting only one line , rest are missing. 
Data I am receiving at server end.

```
 POST /info HTTP/1.1
 User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1    zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
 Host: 192.168.0.57:10000
 Accept: */*
 Content-Length: 356
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 Bhupesh Bhargava
```

In message header it's showing right content length but message body is missing. Any idea where I am doing wrong.
curl command I am using

```
curl --data-binary @/home/bhupesh/data_save2 http://192.168.0.57:10000/info
```

Comment: The only working solution till now I got is `curl --data-binary "$(cat /home/bhupesh/data_save2)" http://192.168.0.57:10000/info
` but still I am not clear about it

Answer (score 0):

The curl command seems to be OK and if we go by [the documentation here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-binary), the following should be true.

> Data is posted in a similar manner as --data-ascii does, except that
>   newlines are preserved and conversions are never done.

So, this leaves us with the fact that there should be a problem in your Server implementation. It is not quite sure how you are getting the received stuff at the server, but you should be careful about sequencing what you receive by yourself. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6090610/782094) is an example how you could do that.